# pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError in Mongodb

Tags: python, pymongo-3.x

I am getting error when I try to insert dictionary in the mongodb.
Here are the things I am using:
Python: 3.9.4
Pymongo: 3.11.4
**My Code:**

```
import pymongo
import urllib 

client = pymongo.MongoClient(urllib.parse.quote_plus("mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@posts.xrg19.mongodb.net/<DBname>?ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE"))

db = client['MyBlog']
collection= db['Posts']
dic={"Name":'Naruto',"Rank":'Hokage'}
collection.insert_one(dic)
```

**My Error:**
[In visual studio code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZUYb.png)

**Sorry for any mistake this is my first question**